# SSH.Paramiko.Command execution failure

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

The question to network ingineers.
Why does the HP Router executes the command "display version", but failes to execute the command "display arp". The session is just hanging...
But at the same time execution of "display arp 10.241.178.2 " is finishing fine.

This is a HP device and "dis arp" command must be working for sure.

```
 try:
    print("\n!!!Connecting to "+ip_connect+"!!!\n\n")
    session = paramiko.SSHClient()
    session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    session.connect(ip_connect,username=a, password=b, timeout=20)
    time.sleep(2)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = session.exec_command('display version\n')
    data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
    print data
    time.sleep(2)
    session.close()
except paramiko.SSHException:
    print("!FAILED!")
```

One more example:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = session.exec_command('display arp | i D\n')
```

Output:

```
<>
                Type: S-Static    D-Dynamic
IP Address       MAC Address     VLAN ID  Interface              Aging Type
<>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It just doesnt want to show me the table itself, I dont know why.

Comment: Are you waiting for input from a command that have no output? How about `session.exec_command('display arp && echo OK\n')`?

Comment: The command "dis arp" is well executed if you print it on a device and it gives out whole arp table

Comment: Ok, it is a switch or something like that... Not a bash shell - please ignore the `echo` test.

Comment: Successfully ignored )

Comment: This is odd behavior; at the same time it is hard for us to diagnose because we don't have access to your device in order to reproduce the problem. So it is a wild guess but have you tried sending more than one "\n" or sending "\r\n" or "\r" or "\n\r" instead?

Comment: Yes, man, I tried many variations of it experimenting with space symbols and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Netmiko insted of Paramiko and it has solved my problem!